# A non-trivial closed polynomial function must not be surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a nonconstant polynomial function.

If $f$ is a closed mapping, then $f$ must not be a surjection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have tried so far? also are you sure that algebraic geometry tag is relevant?

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg I want a proof of "A non-trival closed polynomial function must not be surjective".

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I guess you can solve it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED:

If there is a sequence of points $p_n$ with $|p_n| \to \infty$ and $f(p_n)$ bounded, then there is a (maybe different) sequence forming a closed set $S$ such that $f(S)$ is not closed.  Show that if there is no such sequence $p_n$, then $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} f(z)$ is either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: @DavidChan: If there are arbitrarily large points $z$ such that $f(z)$ is large and positive and also arbitrarily large points $z'$ such that $f(z')$ is large and negative, then there must be arbitrarily large points $p$ such that $f(p)$ is $0$ (because you can find a path from $z$ to $z'$ that stays far away from the origin).  The reason this argument works for $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not $\mathbb{R}$ is that the complement of a ball around the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, whereas in $\mathbb{R}$ it is disconnected.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I know if $f$ is proper then $f$ is closed. But this answer tell me for polynomial, a closed mapping must be a proper mapping? And I have known that $f$ is unbounded, but $f$ must be surjective?

Comment: @DavidChan:  Yes, that is what the first sentence of this answer says: if $f$ sends an unbounded sequence to a bounded sequence, then by taking a convergent subsequence of the image sequence and moving the points slightly to be sure the limit is not equal to any of the points of the sequence, you get a closed set $S$ such that $f(S)$ is not closed.  I'm afraid I don't understand your second question.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Why "$f$ is a proper mapping, so $f$ is not surjective"? I can't find this.

Answer (score 1):

Let me flesh out (and slightly rephrase) the details in Robert Israel's beautiful answer a bit.  Suppose $f$ is surjective.  Let $D_n\subset\mathbb{R}$ denote the closed disk of radius $n$ centered at the origin.  Then for any $n$, there exist $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus D_n$  such that $f(x)<-1$ and $f(y)>1$ (if, for instance, no such $x$ existed, then the image of $f$ would be bounded below since $f(D_n)$ is compact and outside of $D_n$, $f$ is always above $-1$).  Since $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus D_n$ is connected, we can find a point $z_n\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus D_n$ such that $f(z_n)=1/n$.  Now let $S=\{z_n\}$.  Since $z_n\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus D_n$ for all $n$, $S$ contains only finitely many points in any bounded set, so $S$ is closed.  But $f(S)=\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$ is not closed.  Thus $f$ is not a closed map.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood just know.