# Does there exist a polynomial function both open and closed?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a nonconstant polynomial function.

Does there exist a polynomial $f$ such that $f$ is an open map and meanwhile a closed map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is both closed and open, then $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is clopen, so it must be all of $\mathbb{R}$.  But by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1493400/86856), if $f$ is closed, then it cannot be surjective.