# A closed polynomial function must be proper?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a nonconstant polynomial function.

If $f$ is a closed mapping, then for any point $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(y)$ must be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Some linked about the following questions: [A non-trivial closed polynomial function must not be surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493385/a-non-trivial-closed-polynomial-function-must-not-be-surjective)
and [Does there exist a polynomial function both open and closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494797/does-there-exist-a-polynomial-function-both-open-and-closed)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  Suppose $f$ is closed and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is not compact for some $y\in \mathbb{R}$.  Then $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is unbounded; choose an sequence of points $(p_n)$ such that $p_n\to\infty$ and $f(p_n)=y$ for each $n$.  Since $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial, it is not locally constant anywhere, so for each $n$, we can find a point $q_n$ near $p_n$ such that $$0<|f(q_n)-y|<1/n.$$

The set $S=\{q_n\}$ is then a closed set such that $f(S)$ is not closed.